# Measuring response time in AFNetworking HTTP GET

Tags: ios, ios6, afnetworking, nsoperationqueue

I am trying to measure time taken per GET request when downloading a file using AFNetworking. I am downloading a file repeatedly in a loop. 
The problem I am having is that the way I am measuring total time, it gives a much larger total time than it actually is. For example, for 50 downloads it gives 72 sec but in reality it only took around 5 sec. I also suspect 5 sec is too low for 50 downloads(the download size is 581 kb per file).

How do I effectively measure time in this case? I need time from the moment request is fired till response in received.

My method to download file:

```
- (void) HTTPGetRequest
{    
    startTime = CACurrentMediaTime(); // Start measuring time

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:http://myServer];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                            path:@"/download/Text581KB.txt"
                                                      parameters:nil];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

    // Save downloaded file
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text581KB.txt"]];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        double elapsedTime = (CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime); // Measuring time
        totalTime += elapsedTime; // Measuring total time HERE!
        [results setString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Current Transaction Time: %f sec\nTotal Time: %f sec", elapsedTime, totalTime]];
        [_resultLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:results waitUntilDone:NO];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {  ((int)totalBytesExpectedToWrite));
        totalDownloadSize += totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
        [_DataTransferredLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total Download Size: %@", [self getFileSize:totalDownloadSize/1024]]];
    }];

    [operation setCacheResponseBlock:^NSCachedURLResponse *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse) {
        return nil;
    }];
    [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

I am creating a NSOperationQueue in my viewDidLoad:

```
operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
[operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1]; // using this as I was suspecting downloads were happening in parallel & thus 50 downloads finishing in a few secs
```

I am invoking the HTTPGetRequest method as follows:

```
- (IBAction)startDownload:(UIButton *)sender {
    totalCount = [[_countText text] longLongValue]; // get # of times to download
    long currentCount = 1;
    completedCount = 0;
    totalTime = 0;
    totalDownloadSize = 0;
    while (currentCount <= totalCount)
    {
        [self HTTPGetRequest];
        [results setString:@""];
        currentCount++;

    }
```

Comment: look how the time measurement is done in `AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger` https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger/blob/master/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger.m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of calculating cumulative time (not elapsed time), I have just created a subclass of `AFHTTPRequestOperation` that captures the start time. Otherwise, you won't know precisely when it started:

```
@interface TimedAFHTTPRequestOperation : AFHTTPRequestOperation

@property (nonatomic) CFAbsoluteTime startTime;

@end

@implementation TimedAFHTTPRequestOperation

- (void)start
{
    self.startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

    [super start];
}

@end
```

(Note I'm using `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` versus `CACurrentMediaTime`; use whatever you want, but just be consistent.)

Then in the code that's doing the downloads, you can use this `TimedAFHTTPRequestOperation` instead of `AFHTTPRequestOperation`:

```
TimedAFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[TimedAFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
```

That code's completion block can then use the `startTime` property of `TimedAFHTTPRequestOperation` to calculate the time elapsed for the given operation and add it to the total time:

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    TimedAFHTTPRequestOperation *timedOperation = (id)operation;
    CFTimeInterval elapsedTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - timedOperation.startTime;
    self.totalTime += elapsedTime; // Measuring total time HERE!
    NSLog(@"finished in %.1f", elapsedTime);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

That's how you calculate the `elapsedTime` and append them together to calculate the `totalTime`.

In terms of how to know when the operations are done, I would

- modify `HTTPGetRequest` to return a `NSOperation`;
- have `startDownload` create a completion operation and then add all of these operations as dependencies:

  ```
  NSOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
      NSLog(@"finished all in cumulative time: %.1f", self.totalTime);
  }];

  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < totalCount; i++)
  {
      NSOperation *operation = [self HTTPGetRequest];
      [completionOperation addDependency:operation];
  }
  [self.operationQueue addOperation:completionOperation];
  ```

That achieves several goals, namely creating a completion operation, calculating the total time (as opposed to the total time elapsed).

By the way, I'd also suggest pulling the creation of `AFHTTPClient` out of your `HTTPGetRequest`. You should probably only create one per app. This is especially important in case you ever started using `enqueueHTTPRequestOperation` instead of creating your own operation queue. I also see no need for your call to `registerHTTPOperationClass`.

---

You are incrementing the `totalElapsed` by `elapsedTime`, but `elapsedTime` is calculated from `startTime`, which itself represents the time that the jobs were first queued, not when the download actually started. Remember that `HTTPGetRequest` returns almost immediately (having set `elapsedTime`). Thus if you're queueing five downloads, I wouldn't be surprised that `HTTPGetRequest` runs five times (and sets and resets `startTime` five times) before the first request even is initiated.

The question is further complicated by the question of whether you're doing concurrent downloads, and if so, what you then mean by "total elapsed". Let's say you have two concurrent downloads, one that takes 5 seconds, another takes 7 seconds. Do you want the answer to be 7 (because they both finished in 7 seconds)? Or do you want the answer to be 12 (because they both finished in a cumulative 12 seconds)?

I'm presuming that you're looking for, in this scenario, 7 seconds, then you should set the `startTime` once before you initiate all of your requests, and then only calculate when all of the downloads are done. You could, for example, rather than doing any calculations in `HTTPGetRequest` at all, just add your own operation that is dependent upon all the other operations you added, which calculates the total elapsed. at the very end. Or, if you want the the total elapsed to just reflect the total elapsed while you're in the process of downloading, then just set `totalElapsed` rather than incrementing it.

Comment: I am looking for cumulative time.
I tried using an operation to calculate time at the end and added it as a dependency to the HTTP GET operation but somehow that operation never gets called. I have this inside the HTTPGetRequest method:
`NSInvocationOperation *to = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finish) object:nil];`, finish method just NSLogs a string. Added as dependency `[to addDependency:operation];` but can't see the string printed to console.

Comment: @RBK I've updated my answer with code sample that calculated total cumulative download times as well as a completion operation that works like you'd expect.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. I've got it to work now. I had to add `[operationQueue addOperation:operation];` inside the for loop which you'v shown for it to start running the operations. I've removed the call to `registerHTTPOperationClass`. I had got the code stub from the net & just copied it over without looking. How do I move the `AFHTTPClient` our of the `HTTPGetRequest` method since I init it with a `NSMutableURLRequest` which is defined inside that method.

Comment: @RBK - You can make the `AFHTTPClient` variable a class property or ivar, then you can set it in `startDownload` and use it in `HTTPRequest`. By the way, it looks like you're using a serial queue, so you can measure the elapsed time without resorting to my expanded answer. When I wrote that, I was under the impression you were using concurrent downloads. I hadn't noticed that you had `maxConcurrentOperationCount` set to `1`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I too realized it now that I can get the total time without the `completionOperation` operation.

Answer (score 7):

Use [AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to inject the "fire" date in the operation's userInfo by observing the AFNetworkingOperationDidStartNotification notification.

```
//AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [...]
id __block observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:AFNetworkingOperationDidStartNotification
        object:operation
         queue:nil
    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                   operation.userInfo = @{@"fireDate": [NSDate date]};
                   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observer];
              }];
```

Comment: Like this idea, but why use a notification for that, why not just set the date on the operation user info just before calling [operation start] ?

Comment: Because sometimes you just enqueue the operation among many others and then don't really (want to) have control over when it really starts.